# jdk not found aws sam application visual studio code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, visual-studio-code, aws-sam-cli

I want to debug a java8 (aws) project with visual studio code, so I created with vscode a new sam application runtimes.
In the list of runtimes, I can't found java8 despite it is installed and specified in settings.json

> "java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"

Comment: Try a double slash like:`"java.home": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_161"`

Comment: tried. doesn't work, vscode can't find the jdk

Comment: Do you configure JDK system environment variables?

Comment: yes, this is my java home: JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221

Comment: maybe you should try reinstall the jdk